# How to enable DHCP automatically on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, dhcp

I am using Windows 10 14393.1358 on a ThinkPad 13 with an Intel 8260 WiFi card. On startup, the WiFi card is able to connect to a network, but is unable to access the internet till I manually enable DHCP by changing the IPv4 settings to 'Obtain an IP address automatically' in the Network Connections panel as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to make this setting permanent so I don't have to manually change it on every reboot?

Comment: Use this command `netsh int ip set address "Ethernet" dhcp`

Comment: Will this set it permanently?

Comment: Yes. The command set it for permanently untill you uninstall that interface.

Comment: The changes you’re making are already supposed to be permanent. Do you have a third-party WiFi management tool installed?

Comment: I suggest installing the current feature update to see if the problem will go away your using 1607 where as 1703 is the current build

Comment: @DanielB I have a trial version of Connectify, but removing that hasn't helped. Doing a Windows 10 update hasn't helped matters either.